# How to flush / garbage collect GPU memory - Windows 10 - Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

Some of the applications / game i play have GPU memory leakage

The gpu memory used gets increased over time

Even after I close the game / apps gpu used memory is still there

When I disable GPU from device manager and enable back GPU memory is cleared

But I wonder if there is any software / command etc to flush GPU memory?

I have Geforce GTX 1050 Ti and I am using Windows 10

Comment: Have you looked into commands you can run that will disable and enable the GPU? Or, if the GPU driver has a command you can run that will flush the cache? This will be documented by the card manufacturer and so will be as available to you as it is to us.

Answer (score 2):

If the graphics memory usage persists after closing the application, there's probably a graphics driver bug involved. Regular GPU programming APIs wouldn't help with that.

Windows offers a sort-off undocumented keyboard shortcut to quickly restart the graphics driver:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Maybe that's enough of a workaround until updated drivers without the bug are released. Restarting the graphics driver may crash less resilient applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get a toggle off/on going though a powershell script like so.

- Open Windows Powershell ISE and copy paste the following code into it

  {

  #Disable the GPU

  Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "GPU NAME" | Disable-PnpDevice

  #Adjust wait time to any amount you want

  Sleep -Seconds 5

  #Enable the GPU

  Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "GPU NAME" | Enable-PnpDevice

  }
- Replace "GPU NAME" with the exact name of your GPU as seen inside device manager. This is the "Friendly Name". Not all commands work with friendly name though so you might need to use the `-Deviceid` argument instead of `-FriendlyName` and retrieve the Deviceid by right clicking > properties on the GPU inside device manager.
- Save the script to your desktop and right click > run with powershell

This should now toggle your GPU off/on. For other ways to clear the ram cache you'll have to check out the NVIDIA development forum. There are some things you can script with NVIDIA GPU's. A few sample scripts should be available for you to check out here on your local C Drive:

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA WMI Provider\Samples

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue for few months and looking for same answer. I think the VRAM usage is slowly increasing even on idle.

Also, on restart, the card is installed again, getting a new instance ID.
I did rolled back the driver, but the issue remained.

I use this script to find the right instance ID and do the toggle.

```DOS
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem -params-
set select_field=Device Description
set select_value=3060
set instance_id=none
rem set "instance_id=PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2489&SUBSYS_88501043&REV_A1\4&1f822d9d&0&0008"
rem -params-end---change with care below this line

rem daca ID-ul e dat, se face chestia.
if /i "%instance_id%" neq "none" goto thething
rem altfel...
set value=none
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ('pnputil /enum-devices /class Display') do (
    rem elimina din %value%  textul cautat; 
    call set "test=%%value:%select_value%=%%"
    rem daca ramane la fel inseamna ca nu il are - deci ia urmatorul instance_id
    if /i "!value!" == "!test!" (
        set value=none
        if "%%A" == "Instance ID" set "tmp_id=%%B"
        if "%%A" == "%select_field%" for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%K in ("%%B") do set "value=%%K"
    ) else (
        set "instance_id=!tmp_id!"
        rem eliminat spatiu din fata (nu merge cu for ca are "&")
        set "instance_id=!instance_id:~16!"
    )
    rem daca e disconected seteaza value=none - ca sa treaca mai departe
    if "%%A" == "Status" (
        set "test=%%B"
        set test=!test:Disconnected=!
        if /i "!test!" neq "%%B" (
            set value=none
            set instance_id=none
        )
    )
)
echo selectie: %select_field% ~ %select_value% = %value%
echo rezultat instance ID: !instance_id!
rem daca nu s-a gasit
if /i "%instance_id%" == "none" (
    echo NUP... vezi mai jos:
    echo.
    pnputil /enum-devices /class Display
    echo.
    goto ending
)

rem verificare administrator
net session >nul 2>&1
if not %errorLevel% == 0 (
    echo.
    echo -- Trebuie deschis cu "Run as Administrator" -- 
    echo.
    goto ending
) 


:thething
pnputil /disable-device "%instance_id%"
timeout 2
pnputil /enable-device "%instance_id%"

:ending
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's your browser that's hogging the resources, there are typically internal page URI's that can trigger the release/refresh.  For example, for Google Chrome, you can type into the omnibox: `chrome://gpuclean` and hit enter.